# Joi - how to check when other key's value is null/empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, schema, joi

I am having trouble trying to validate a JSON file, to be more specific I am having trouble with a **when** condition.

I have a **a** key that has to be a past date, and isn't required. Then I have a **b** key that should be an url and *if* **a** *is null/empty,* **b** *can be empty, otherwise must be required*.

I'll leave my code below to make it clear, but right now I'm not getting any error if **b** is null but **a** isn't.

```
a: Joi.date().less("now").raw().optional().allow(null, ""),
b: Joi.string()
  .uri({ scheme: [/https?/] })
  .when("a", {
    is: Joi.any().empty(),
    then: Joi.optional().allow(null, ""),
    otherwise: Joi.required(),
  }),
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the solution, my **is** condition was wrong.

Instead of using *is: Joi.any().empty()* I put *is: Joi.any().valid(null, "")* and it worked.

So the solution is this:

```
a: Joi.date().less("now").raw().optional().allow(null, ""),
b: Joi.string()
  .uri({ scheme: [/https?/] })
  .when("a", {
    is: Joi.any().valid(null, ""),
    then: Joi.optional().allow(null, ""),
    otherwise: Joi.required(),
  }),
```